# Converting c++ OpenGL code to C# OpenTK

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, opentk

I've messed with OpenGL in c++ a little but I'd like to test it in a language I'm more familiar in.

I've taken an example from the OpenGL red book (the very first one as far as I'm aware) which is the following:

```
#include <whateverYouNeed.h>

main() {

   InitializeAWindowPlease();

   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex3f (0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
   glEnd();
   glFlush();

   UpdateTheWindowAndCheckForEvents();
}
```

I'm trying to make the exact same thing using the OpenTK wrapper for C#, here's what I came up with:

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEST2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (GameWindow gameWindow = new GameWindow())
            {
                gameWindow.Load += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    gameWindow.VSync = VSyncMode.On;
                    gameWindow.Title = "Test";
                };

                gameWindow.Resize += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    GL.Viewport(0, 0, gameWindow.Width, gameWindow.Height);
                };

                gameWindow.UpdateFrame += (sender, e) =>
                {

                };

                gameWindow.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    //Here's the main content of the 'converted' code
                    GL.ClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
                    GL.Color3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    GL.Ortho(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Polygon);
                        GL.Vertex3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
                        GL.Vertex3(0.75f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
                        GL.Vertex3(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
                        GL.Vertex3(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
                    GL.End();
                    GL.Flush();
                    gameWindow.SwapBuffers();
                };

                gameWindow.Run(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I *assumed* this would do is display a white box on a black background like the OpenGL example apparently does, but it doesn't seem to work... What is it I've done wrong? Is it my window handling?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Your window is plain black ? Is `RenderFrame` called ?

Comment: Yes sorry, the window displayed is plain black. Yes the renderframe is definitely being called because if i comment out `GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);` I do get the white box, and for approx 50% of the frames its in the correct position, but for those other 50% of frames its in the bottom left of the black window but still the correct size, just its bottom left corner is in the same position as the bottom left corner of the black window - not centered like it should be.

Comment: Also, when the GL.Clear is Uncommented it appears that the box appears for approx. 2 frames then never displays again, the first frame with the box being in the incorrect position, the second frame with the box being in the correct position, and all frames past this being completely black, so while it does do _something_ its not doing anything near the _right thing_

Comment: Got it. Add GL.LoadIdentity() before GL.Ortho(...). The point is, your render code is called many times, where it's only called once in the c++ example. You must reset the matrix every time, or you accumulate transformations and everything looks wrong.

Comment: Oh right i see, yes that's sorted it. It would of never clicked to see that, Thanks for your help.